# Pandas: I want to create a column in a Time Series where the value depends on the previous row's value

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, time-series, forecasting

I have a time series dataframe where I need to create a boolean-valued column,
which is

- **True** if the current value is more than 10% different from the previous row's value.
- **False** otherwise

Comment: Try posting some sample data, and the code you have tried so far, and some data with the expected output.

Answer (score 1):

As you have not provided any sample data, so I am not 100% sure, what you exactly want.
But here is what I think you need to do

```
df=pd.DataFrame([np.random.randn(10,1)],columns=['first'])
df['prev']=df.shift(1)
df['prev']-df['first']>df['first']*0.1
```